# Oracle Select for update not working and sometimes hangs after while

Tags: java, database, oracle, transactions

Im doing a Oracle Select for Update with java and it works on times and sometimes it hangs with the session and cannot remove the locked session (have to manually kill the session )
this works fine for most of the scenarios but when I deployed it in two servers ( web service ) and request them both at once this happens , I can't understand whether it's a problem with my code , 
my code

```
 public boolean checkJobStatus(long taskId)
{
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement selectForUpdate = null;
    String lastJobStatus = null;
    boolean runNow = false;
    try
    {
        con = conPool.getConnection();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        selectForUpdate  = con.prepareStatement("SELECT LAST_JOB_STATUS FROM ADM_JOB WHERE TASK_ID = ? FOR UPDATE ");
        selectForUpdate.setLong(1, taskId);
        ResultSet resultSet = selectForUpdate.executeQuery();

        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            if (resultSet.getObject("LAST_JOB_STATUS") == null)
            {
                lastJobStatus = ScheduledJob.STATUS_FAILED;
            }
            else
            {
                lastJobStatus = resultSet.getString("LAST_JOB_STATUS");
            }
        }

     if(ScheduledJob.STATUS_RUNNING.equalsIgnoreCase(lastJobStatus) || ScheduledJob.STATUS_STARTED.equalsIgnoreCase(lastJobStatus))
     {
         runNow = false;
         // commit n update setting autocommit to true
         selectForUpdate = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE ADM_JOB SET LAST_JOB_STATUS =? WHERE TASK_ID = ?");
         selectForUpdate.setString(1, lastJobStatus);
         selectForUpdate.setLong(2, taskId);
         selectForUpdate.executeUpdate();
     }
     else
     {
         runNow =true;
         // commit n update setting autocommit to true
         selectForUpdate  = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE ADM_JOB SET LAST_JOB_STATUS =? WHERE TASK_ID = ?");
         selectForUpdate.setString(1, ScheduledJob.STATUS_STARTED);
         selectForUpdate.setLong(2, taskId);
         selectForUpdate.executeUpdate();

         con.commit();
         con.setAutoCommit(true);
     }

    } catch (SQLException e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger( "" ).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error in getting database connection", e);
        try
        {
            con.rollback();   // rolling back the row lock in case of a exception
        } catch (SQLException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        DBUtility.close( selectForUpdate  );
        DBUtility.close( con );
    }


    return runNow;
}
```

Comment: Usually "For Update" is used with cursors, which you're not really doing here. Record lock is released on commit or rollback, but you're only committing when you run the started state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commit occurs only in the else branch. If this condition doesn't happen, transaction is not closed, so a second thread hangs up forever on the select for update.

Comment: thank you Simimmo it really worked , thought updating does the commit it self .